# Tensorboard cannot import name `run_main`

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Ever since I have updated to TensorFlow v1.4, I have not been able to run TensorBoard. Originally I was getting a problem related to `flags` (as I posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399965/tensorboard-error-after-upgrading-to-1-4-trying-to-access-flag-before-flags-wer)). In fact, I reinstalled TensorFlow with the understanding that a fix was in, but now I am getting this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
ImportError: cannot import name 'run_main'
```

I am getting this error regardless of whether I provide a log directory. What is the fix and what can I do to investigate?

I am fairly new to the Tensorflow ecoysystem. What I tried to do was open the file referenced above `/opt/python/3.6.3/bin/tensorboard`. I saw the following:

```
#!/opt/python/3.6.3/bin/python3.6

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from tensorboard.main import run_main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run_main())
```

I looked at `tensorboard.main` where I saw nothing named `run_main` but I did see a `def main` so I tried changing the `import run_main` and `run_main()` to `main` but that led me back to the `flags` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also opened an issue about this on the tensorboard issues page: <https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/812>

Comment: @herrtim thanks for confirming I am not the only one. What I found was when I downloaded and installed  Tensorboard directly rather than the one associated with the TF git, everything works (finally!)

Answer (score 5):

From here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/812

```
 pip install tb-nightly
```

It indicates the following there

> If you're building TensorFlow from source please pip install tb-nightly.